# Comma with dates - oddity

Tags: oxford-comma

I KNOW the rule is to put a comma after full dates, but in this case, it seems to be a bit much: "...the contract runs from July 1, 2015 through July 31, 2016, and should be amended as such. Because it's "x" through "y" it seems to put a comma after 2015 is too many commas. Thoughts?

Comment: Seems fine to me. It would probably also be fine without, but I prefer it with.

Comment: The way you have written it implies American English.  Is that what you are after?  Date formats vary around the world.

Comment: In American business communication, I don't think anyone would blink. If it really bothers you, you could add more separating words: *the contract will run for the period beginning on July 1, 2015, and ending on July 31, 2016, and should be amended as such.*

Comment: Not 'the rule'. 'One way of writing it.'

Comment: I don't see any need for the comma after the year (though I'm sure that some authorities prescribe it).  In the above example the comma after 2016 fits, since there is a natural pause there, but I see no need for a comma after 2015.

Comment: I (a Brit) have *never* heard of a rule about commas in dates. The comma you already have in "July 1, 2015" looks strange to me. But then (being British) I'd put the day before the month anyway: "the contract runs from 1 July 2015 to" - no commas needed or expected.

Answer (score 3):

Commas must *bracket* the year numbers, as parenthetical, if you are using this style for writing dates. If that results in just too many commas for your taste, switch styles:

> . . . the contract runs from 1 July 2015 through 31 July 2016, and should be amended as such.

Comment: The year isn't a "parenthetical".  The comma between date and year is simply being used to visually separate the two numbers.

Answer (score 2):

As written, a strange relationship is made between 2015 and July 31. With the comma after the year, it seems more clear the relationship is between the entire dates. What's stranger is when the date is used as an adjective:

> Our July 1, 2015, appointment was enlightening.

Of course, you could switch styles, but hopefully you see why all commas come required in this one.

Comment: I think the comma after 2015 above is simply confusing.  It's like you're saying there are two unrelated clauses.